# How do you implement CRUD on a complex simpleDb entity

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-simpledb

I have a complex object:

```
ItemName (single only)
Client (single only)
Provider (single only)
Attribute1 (multiple allowed)
Attribute2 (multiple allowed)
Attribute... (multiple allowed)
```

I have an object in C#:

```
public class MyJobModel
    {
        public Dictionary<string,List<string>> JobAttributes { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string Client { get; set; }
        public string DataProvider { get; set; }
        public string DataProviderSpecificId { get; set; }
        public MyJobModel()
        {
            JobAttributes = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        }
    }
```

I have a repository and I can query and fill single or multiple by query.

I don't think I'm going to have an issue creating but I do have an issue editing because of the nature of multiple allowed attributes of the same name.

Any suggestion on what to do?

Comment: just wanted to point out the funny paradox of having `complex` and `simpleDb` in the same sentence lol

Comment: More specifics about your SimpleDB code (what libraries are you using if any?) would be helpful to answering your question..

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a look at Ashley Tate's excellent "Simol" (formerly "Simple Savant") library on Codeplex:

http://simol.codeplex.com/